# Using the definite article "the" with adjective before a person's name

Tags: grammar

I am sure this has been asked in the past, but I can't find any rule and I would like to understand what's going on.
"The" is **never** used for proper names, that much I know. When I google "playwright William Shakespeare", it still seems the correct way to say it is without "the". But once I get to "British playwright William Shakespeare", it suddenly seems correct to add "the", as is "the British playwright William Shakespeare". What am I missing and should I still ommit the definite article is the latter case?
TIA
Ruth

Comment: Actually, "the" can be as a determiner with proper names as in "That's not the David Smith that I went to school with". Elsewhere, "the" is typically found with proper names that have nominal modifiers as embellishments, which is what "British playwright" is.

Comment: Or look no further than Donald Trump who refers to himself as *The Donald* or Bruce Springsteen who goes by *The Boss*.

Answer (score 1):

The rule about not using "the" before proper names doesn't apply when you have something descriptive in between: a noun phrase like "British playwright," or even just an adjective like "wonderful." This is a way to refer to someone and also describe them - instead of saying "I want to thank Anna Karenina, who is a wonderful person," you can just say "I want to thank the wonderful Anna Karenina."

That being said, if it is a noun like "playwright," you can also omit the "the" for a slightly different tone that's hard to describe. Maybe a little more formal and respectful. So for example you could say either:

> The British playwright William Shakespeare once wrote, ...

you could say

> British playwright William Shakespeare once wrote, ...

which sounds better to my ear. This works better at the beginning of a sentence.